# Who was the first to write proofs in this manner?

Tags: mathematical-logic, logic

Who was the first to write proofs in this fashion?

[image]

By ``in this fashion'' I mean, using three columns, which go like:

Line number. Premise or assertion. Justification.

Line number. Premise or assertion. Justification.

Etc.

Comment: The specimen above is so-called Fitch-style; see Frederic Brenton Fitch, [Symbolic Logic: An Introduction (Ronald Press, 1952)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/frederic-brenton-fitch-symbolic-logic-an-introduction-the-ronald-press-company-new-york-1952-x-238-s/D62DE330C53AC422C61C0AE174F10E44)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Fitch-style proofs seem close, but don't they involve a sort of indentation that the example doesn't have?

Answer (score 7):

Whitehead & Russel, *Principia Mathematica* (1910) is pretty much like this.

> [image: w&r]

The justifications are on the left, and only certain lines are numbered.

But I doubt it is the first.

Compare Frege's notation for first-order logic (1879):

[image: frege]

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea who is the first to number every premise and assertion *and* number and justify every assertion, without exception? I would suspect that this would happen after Russell and Whitehead, but is there anyone earlier than (say) Irving Copi?